# Unable to set a VPC as a default VPC

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, amazon-vpc

I have 2 VPCs in my account:

```
aws ec2 describe-vpcs --query 'Vpcs[*].VpcId'
[
    "vpc-654bf20c", 
    "vpc-184bf271"
]
```

But when I check my account-attributes, I don't see any default VPC tagged:

```
aws ec2 describe-account-attributes --query 'AccountAttributes[5]'
{
    "AttributeName": "default-vpc", 
    "AttributeValues": [
        {
            "AttributeValue": "none"
        }
    ]
}
```

How do I make any of the VPCs as a default VPC so that when I push stacks using CloudFormation, I don't have to mention VPCs?

Answer (score 4):

You wont be able to convert a non-default VPC into default on your own, you need to get in touch with Amazon support for that. 
If you have UI access to amazon console can you cross check if "`Default VPC`" for either of your VPC is `Yes`. See reference image. 
[image]

If there is none, this means that you have intentionally/mitakenly deleted this VPC in the past. You need to raise a support ticket for getting a new default VPC.

Other work around could be that you move all configurations to some other region, if that is possible, you will get a default VPC there.
Thanks
Hope it helps!

Comment: Onkaar, I 've raised a support case for this. Lets see what they come up with.

Comment: @AlanJebakumar if you have any EC2-Classic resources in the region, you'll have to delete them before AWS will give you a Default VPC.  See [I really want a Default VPC...](https://aws.amazon.com/vpc/faqs/#Default_VPCs)

Comment: @OnkaarSingh *"If there is none, this means that you have intentionally/mitakenly deleted this VPC in the past."*  That's only one possible reason.  [How long ago your AWS account was created](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonVPC/latest/UserGuide/default-vpc.html) is another possible cause of a missing Default VPC.

Comment: @michael, yes i agree with you on this point.. As ec2-classic is not available in newer AWS accounts, hence I didn't mention this point.